# Можно ли в ASP.NET изменить результирующий путь в контроллере без редиректа?

Tags: c#, asp.net, маршрутизация

Могу ли я изменить путь страницы в контроллере без редиректа? Например запрос приходит на сервер по пути "/", а я хочу изменить путь на "/*название города*". Могу ли я сразу отправить представление без использования редиректа?

Comment: Со стороны сервера - нет. Но можете вернуть скрипт, который поменяет url на клиенте через history api без реальной отправки запроса